# Consume Web Service C# Error

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, I have a problem creating and consuming a web service.  I can't provide the URL because it is on a VPN.

First I try from a service reference, the problem is all methods return null and receive null.

Then I try from web service and get:

> There was an error reflecting
>   Method can not be reflected.

I can't access to web service from Url, but I can from SOAPGui.

Any idea why? 
Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the service code? Any chance that service was written in Java? Could be type differences. Might want to check the reference file generated by VS.

Comment: Yes I Have, but the code is generated by visual studio


// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version 4.0.30319.17929.

Comment: I mean the service you are consuming. Do you have access to that? Also, in your reference.cs file for the generated code.